# React ,get 404 when trying to connect localhost to my routs file

Tags: reactjs, api, localhost

trying to connect to my react app from my local host.
trying to get from this http://localhost:8080/api/Data_Schedules
I'm getting 404

this is the code that im trying to get:

routs.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';
import DB from './db';

const router = express.Router();
router.get('localhost:8080/api/Data_Schedules',async(req, res)=>{
    try{
        let Data_Schedules = await DB.Data_Schedules.all();
        res.json(Data_Schedules)
    }
    catch(e){
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
})

export default router;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not sure what you are asking here, but I think you are invoking this endpoint and getting a 404? If so, you probably need to complete the request with a `res.send()`

Comment: Hi ,
thanks for your answer.
I'm trying to get from the browser to the endpoint /api/Data_Schedules and getting 404.
where to put in the code the res.send() request?

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as express from 'express';
import DB from './db';

const router = express.Router();
router.get('/api/Data_Schedules',async(req, res)=>{
    try{
        let Data_Schedules = await DB.Data_Schedules.all();
        res.json(Data_Schedules)
    }
    catch(e){
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
})

export default router;
```